# Implicit differentiation applied to $ z=\frac{1}{y}(f(ax+y)+g(ax-y)). $

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, implicit-differentiation

I'm trying show that

$$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2}=\frac{a^2}{y^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(
y^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})$$knowing that:
$$ z=\frac{1}{y}(f(ax+y)+g(ax-y)). $$
I know that, to do this, I need to use partial differentiation, but I just have no idea where to start. Is there any way I can simplify $f(ax+y)$ and $g(ax-y)$?

Comment: I think you want $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$ instead of $\dfrac{d}{dx},\dfrac{d}{dy}$

Comment: Yes, that is true, but I don't know how to type in the partial derivative symbol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just differentiating.

Since $z=\frac1y[f(ax+y)+g(ax-y)]$, we clearly have
$$
\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}=\frac1y[a^2f''(ax+y)+a^2g''(ax-y)]
$$
on the LHS.
For the RHS, we start by differentiating $z$ with respect to $y$:
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-\frac1{y^2}[f(ax+y)+g(ax-y)]+\frac1y[f'(ax+y)-g'(ax-y)]
$$
So
$$
y^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=-[f(ax+y)+g(ax-y)]+y[f'(ax+y)-g'(ax-y)]
$$
Differentiate with respect to $y$ again,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(y^2\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)&=-[f'(ax+y)-g'(ax-y)]\\
&\quad+[f'(ax+y)-g'(ax-y)]+y[f''(ax+y)+g''(ax-y)]\\
&=y[f''(ax+y)+g''(ax-y)]
\end{align*}
Hence the RHS is
$$
\frac{a^2}{y^2}y[f''(ax+y)+g''(ax-y)]=\frac{a^2}{y}[f''(ax+y)+g''(ax-y)]
$$
So indeed $LHS=RHS$.

Comment: Can you please explain why the $a^2$ appears like that? that's the one bit I don't understand

Comment: It is just the chain rule $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (ax+y)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial(ax+y)}=a\frac{\partial}{\partial(ax+y)}$, similarly $ax-y$.